# How to fix: No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I have huge Java project that fails to run because of this database error

> APPLICATION STARTUP FAILURE
>   No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.ConnectionPool.newConnection(ConnectionPool.java:577)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.ConnectionPool.manageConnections(ConnectionPool.java:470)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.ConnectionPool.getPooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:421)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:355)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:329)
>       at artemispm.serverutil.AppMgr.getConnection(AppMgr.java:492)
>       at artemispm.trjdbc.TRJConnection.(TRJConnection.java:46)
>       at artemispm.trdo.TRBaseSql.getConnection(TRBaseSql.java:2903)
>       at artemispm.service.TRDebugWriter.transmit(TRDebugWriter.java:105)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.clockedTransmit(DataBroker.java:4969)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.callService(DataBroker.java:3125)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.callService(DataBroker.java:3103)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.initTriton(DataBroker.java:325)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.TRApplet.init(TRApplet.java:296)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:425)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> Build Version:?VERSION?
>   productpm.trdo.TRSeriousException: No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.checkError(DataBroker.java:659)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.callService(DataBroker.java:3129)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.callService(DataBroker.java:3103)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.DataBroker.initTriton(DataBroker.java:325)
>       at artemispm.trapplets.TRApplet.init(TRApplet.java:296)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:425)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I tried to placing
sqljdbc.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
in %catalina_home&\lib folder but that did not help

I am not familiar with Java but would appreciate any help on this.

EDIT:
My connections string is defined in customer.properties file like this:
APP.url= sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX

Now I changed it to:
APP.url= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX

and I have new error:

> APPLICATION STARTUP FAILURE Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6
>   is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library,
>   which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

How do I switch to new driver ?

Comment: Try to add sqljdbc.jar into WEB-INF/lib of project.

Comment: Yes I have that file placed there already. Do I need to do anything else except copying it in order to have SQL driver installed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your URL should be `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname`.

Are you sure that you typed it correctly?

Comment: as it says you have to remove sqljdbc.jar and use only sqljdbc4.jar (not both)

Comment: If I leave only sqljdbc4.jar then I get this : 
APPLICATION STARTUP FAILURE
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I have tried both : ading "jdbc:" to the url and adding sqljdbc.jar driver but that did not help, same error

Comment: APPLICATION STARTUP FAILURE No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XX

Comment: Neither of above did not help. Anyone with better idea ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above answers and they alone didn't help me. I had to try some more.

So i tried something else. I copied the "sqljdbc4.jar" file to "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\lib\" and then added "sqljdbc4.jar" to the library of my project. It fixed everything.

I hope this helps those still had trouble.

Answer (score 1):

From sqljdbc_4.0 documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526(v=sql.110).aspx):

Using the sqljdbc.jar class library, applications must first register the driver as follows:
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
When the driver is loaded, you can establish a connection by using a connection URL and the getConnection method of the DriverManager class:

When the getConnection method of the DriverManager class is called, an appropriate driver is located from the set of registered JDBC drivers. sqljdbc4.jar file includes "META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver" file, which contains the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver as a registered driver. The existing applications, which currently load the drivers by using the Class.forName method, will continue to work without modification.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the `sqljdbc4.jar` to the lib folder in the Tomcat folder, and also I added it to my project as well. Still I encountered the same exception. Finally after googling heavily I found that the error is with Tomcat.

Tomcat tries to **prevent memory leaks due to sql server driver**. To overcome the exception, it need to be **disabled** so that it would load the driver automatically.

To disable, change the `server.xml` in Tomcat and make "`JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener`" marked as FALSE.

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

This helped me to prevent following exception and now it works properly.